# vertically align multi-row text within li tag in IE quirks mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer, vertical-alignment, quirks-mode

I'm attempting to find a most cross-browser solution to vertically align text that can span multiple rows within li tags.Here's an example!

[image: OK aligned]

I read a lot about the topic and based on the few threads I assembled the code that can be found on the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xRC3y/15/. This works for most of the browsers, however on IE when pushed in quirks mode via developer tools, it is rendered as follows:

[image: Badly aligned]

I'm struggling to get a solution that works in IE quirks mode as well, and any help is appreciated

Comment: Why do you need it to work in quirks mode?

Comment: Actually your question is quite good. I'm facing a mystery, I have minimized my code, otherwise part of web application, to exactly what I have posted in fiddle, however, the alignment bug does not show in fiddle while it is there on the pages when I run the app. I have no clue why this is so. Also, the bug appears only for ie8 and ie9 in standards mode. In fiddle the bug is there only in quirks mode, I don't know why is this, perhaps due to normalize.css or something I'm missing, but I reconed that if someone has an idea how to fix it for quirks mode, the fix will surely work on the page

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently.  There might be a more elegant solution for this issue, but the way I solved the problem was to conditionally style the element with some Javascript/jQuery.  Unfortunately, this requires you to change your HTML markup by adding the class .vCenterIE7 (or whatever) to the element you want to center and another class .vCenterIE7Rel to the element in which you want the element to be centered.

Also, I know this isn't a completely reliable way to detect whether the user is using IE7 (modernizr is more reliable), but come on, if you're still using IE7 you're probably not manipulating your user agent settings.

Script:

```
function vCenterIE7() {
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie 7') > -1) {
    var els = $('.vCenterIE7');
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
            var c = els.eq(i);
            var b = c.closest('.vCenterIE7Rel');
            var mtop = b.height() / 2;
            mtop -= c.height() / 2;
            c.css('margin-top',mtop);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to detect _quirks mode_, not necessarily IE7. Quirks mode is the default rendering mode in IE5 and earlier, but could relate to any version of IE (up to IE9 I think).

Comment: On a side issue, I'm curious as to why you didn't use a conditional comment to target IE7 and plain CSS to solve your problem? This would seem to be more reliable/efficient and no JavaScript required.

Comment: I was centering my elements by using the display:table-cell trick.  IE7 doesn't support this CSS value for many elements, though, so I was running into problems.  I actually was unaware of any other clean solution for vertical centering (I was trying to avoid CSS expressions), so I wrote my own script to do it.  As for the OP, this method will still work to vertically center your elements, but if you don't have jQuery already running on the page, it's a big investment for something that should be much simpler.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I have voted up your answer as it works, but I would still prefer to accept a CSS only solution. Also, if with your solution you were targeting IE7 and not the quirks mode, you can actually try what is in the fiddle as it works for IE7 (standards mode). Strangely, my problems start with IE8 and IE9